# How to change Burn's default UI Language

Tags: localization, wix, burn

I'm upgrading a Wix installer to a Wix bundle. The installer is for a application that supports only one language, so I need the bundle's UI to be in that same language.

To change the wix installer's UI Language, I used the Language property of the Product tag (1046 is locale code for the language I want):

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Name="My aplication" ... Language="1046">
    ...
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Can I change the Language of the bundle's default UI? How?

[image: burn UI]

My bundle:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle
        Name="..."
        Version="..."
        Manufacturer="..."
        UpgradeCode="...">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
              LicenseUrl=""
              SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
              xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"/>
            <MsiPackage Id="..." SourceFile="..."/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundles don't have a language as they're usually used to install both neutral and many localized resources. WixStdBA automatically tries to show its UI with localized strings matching the user's chosen locale. But if you only ship English strings, for example, only English strings will be shown. You can choose a localization file (.wxl) using the [WixStandardBootstrapperApplication/@LocalizationFile attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html).

(Today, only English strings are available for WixStdBA so you'd have to translate the .wxl strings if you want another language.)

Comment: Where can I find the english version of the wxl file?

Comment: Found it in the Wix Installation dir\SDK\themes